# Â&nbsp; character in SVG (jointjs diagram) on production server

Tags: javascript, svg, encoding, jointjs

I create an SVG diagram using jointjs library. It's like UML diagram.
When I run it locally in develop mode or deploy it into Tomcat locally, it's all ok. But when I deploy it into production/live Tomcat. I get weird characters `Â&nbsp;` instead of space:

[image]

[image]

Backend is Java and UI is Angular. I build the UI in javascript and pass it to Jointjs to build the SVG. The main HTML page that hosts the diagram also has 
`<meta charset="utf-8">` and it's saved in UTF-8 encoding.

Why does it happen on live/production?

Comment: Setting the encoding in the document itself is the last resort. If the server declares a different encoding in HTTP headers the browser will possibly use that. and I suspect you're relying on the default encoding configured in whatever server you deploy to.

Comment: Impossible to tell from your PNG images. But perhaps the Javascript is being served with a different charset?

Comment: Server response header has `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8` and it has the correct encoding. I suspect it's sth on the client side. Javascript na d HTML files are all in UFT-8